# How do I link C++ (Visual Studio 2010) to an image-outputting event listener?

Tags: c++, user-interface, event-handling

I am writing a very simple program in C++ that listens to keyboard input, but what I want to output is much more difficult than I expected. For every key I press, I want an image (specific to the key) to appear on the screen. For example, let's say if I press the "O" key, an image of Earth appears on my screen.

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: where do you want it to appear on the screen? for how long? etc. etc. you need to tell more details

Comment: It doesn't matter where on the screen, and preferably I would like to control for how long (but if no such parameter exists and it just stays on the screen, that's okay too). I know that it is possible to do this using system() and opening a JPG, but I'd like to find something that is part of the program. For example, if I press a different key, a different image comes up and the previous image disappears.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with layered windows. I have created a Win32 project as a demo. You can find the code and explanations [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2011/08/04/display-images-as-you-type-in-cpp/).

Basically you have to:

- handle the WM_CHAR message and load the appropriate image (from resources or from disk)
- create a layered window and display the loaded image in that window
- if you want to automatically close the window after an given interval after the last key was pressed you have to create a timer and in the timed procedure destroy the window

Check my link for a solution to your problem.